# drag file to browser from local

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I want drop jpg to Browser from local, and display it on Browser.

I write code, but it don't display jpg.

Please advice.

html

```
<img id="img1" ondragover="doDragOver(event);"
               ondrop="doDrop(event);" 
               class="droppable">
```

css

```
.droppable {
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        background-color: gray;
}
```

script

```
function doDragOver(event){
    var type = event.dataTransfer.types.contains("Files");
    if (type){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

function doDrop(event){
    var img = document.getElementById("img1");
    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function() {
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's browser not "browzer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `dragOver` function the type list is empty (to it's empty in some browsers), but why check it content? You can check it in the drop function.

Be sure to cancel the default browser behavior using `event.preventDefault();` and `return false`

Code:

```
function doDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false
}

function doDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var img = document.getElementById("img1");
    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Up2NF/